# Can people find math.SE questions with identities/inequalities from Google?

Tags: discussion, search

One thing that I love about math.SE is the idea that people googling math quesitons will find well researched, well thought-out answers to their questions here. However, how does this work when key parts of the question are written in LaTeX/math notation? E.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037657/lower-bound-on-p-that-satisfies-p-choose-n-geq-c/2038153#2038153) that I just asked and later found an answer to myself. It's certainly a question other people will have at one point or another, but how would they ever find it? Does math.SE have any strategy to make questions like this accessible from search engines etc? What kind of strategies would even theoretically be possible?

Comment: Strive to include appropriate keywords / buzzwords that those searching might use. That's useful elsewhere too, e.g. I insert fairly unique phrases in posts that allow me to compose queries linking to posts on various topics, [multiplicative telescopy,](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+multiplicative+telescopy) and [denominator ideals](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22denominator+ideal%22), and even [*uniqueness theorems* provide powerful tools for proving equalities](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+uniqueness+powerful+tools+equalities)

Comment: Try approach0: https://approach0.xyz

Comment: See this [similar Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10169/how-to-search-for-a-formula-expression) on Meta.Math.SE about searching for formulas generally, particularly Martin Sleziak's comment there linking to other such posts.